# Can you identify these parts and assemblies?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

I just spent a lovely afternoon going through a box of childhood (40+ years ago) identifying bricks, but ended with a half dozen I couldn't. Here is a picture:

[image]

I know some are newer, but some are original (3 & 6)

If you could help me find the actual part numbers I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. [Brick, Modified 1 x 2 with Digger Bucket Arm Holder](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3317) and [Vehicle, Digger Bucket Arm, Small - 2 x 6 x 2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3314)
2. [Windscreen 5 x 2 x 1 2/3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6070)
3. This is a broken [Hook Slope 45 2 x 3 x 1 1/3 Double with Arm and Light Gray Tow Hook](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3135c02)
4. Both `a` and `b` are an assembly of [Brick, Modified 1 x 1 with Headlight](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4070) with [Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Light Attachment - Thick Ring](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4081b)
5. Combination on [Hinge Brick 1 x 2 Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3937) and [Hinge Brick 1 x 2 Top Plate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3938)
6. Assembly of [Plate, Modified 1 x 4 with Tow Ball](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3184) and [Plate, Modified 1 x 4 with Tow Ball Socket, Long, 4 Slots (8mm Socket Length)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3183b)